# VSO NuGet Publisher Build Step Fails

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-artifacts

I am using Visual Studio Online - Package Manager Preview, along with the new build system. The package manager preview adds a number of build steps, including a "NuGet Publisher" step, which should push packages to the private feed hosted by Visual Studio Online.

Now the [documentation is a little out of step here](http://visualstudio.com/get-started/package/what-is-packaging). As is the [documentation on auth](https://www.visualstudio.com/get-started/package/use/auth) and [personal access tokens](https://www.visualstudio.com/get-started/package/use/auth#personal-access-tokens). There are some indications that you shouldn't need auth between VSO and the Package Manager as long as you have permissions set up (the build service account has permissions to the service endpoint and to the package manager extension). The actual build step asks you to select from your list of Service Endpoints, so that is what I have attempted.

When I place no credentials on the Service Endpoint, I get the error:

```
Server Key must be set, set the password on the generic service
```

When I attempt to place the API key against the Service Endpoint it seems to be discarded on save... and the error changes to:

```
2015-11-18T08:35:24.5678951Z Invoking nuget with push C:\a\1\s\EventViewer\bin\Release\Project.Name.1.1.12.0.nupkg -s https://example.pkgs.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/_packaging/example/nuget/v3/index.json usfusmx4ez6mlfqwpp2abzc7e37denfcp7bxsep2hqij3tp4qwvq on C:\a\1\s\EventViewer\bin\Release\Project.Name.1.1.12.0.nupkg
2015-11-18T08:35:24.5688946Z C:\LR\MMS\Services\Mms\TaskAgentProvisioner\Tools\agents\default\agent\worker\tools\NuGet.exe push C:\a\1\s\EventViewer\bin\Release\Project.Name.1.1.12.0.nupkg -s https://example.pkgs.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/_packaging/Example/nuget/v3/index.json usfusmx4ez6mlfqwpp2abzc7e37denfcp7bxsep2hqij3tp4qwvq
2015-11-18T08:35:25.3467312Z Please provide credentials for: https://example.pkgs.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/_packaging/Example/nuget/v3/index.json
2015-11-18T08:35:25.3667189Z ##[error]Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
2015-11-18T08:35:25.3677179Z UserName: Password: 
2015-11-18T08:35:25.4647059Z ##[error]Unexpected exit code 1 returned from tool NuGet.exe
```

I have also attempted to use a personal access token to no avail.

How do I get the publish step working?

Comment: I think my problem is that the "Project Build Service" doesn't have permission to the feed. The bad news is that the auto-completion feature only shows the first 20 results and the GUID I need isn't in the first 20 (and adding some from that list doesn't stop them being displayed).

Comment: Your first doc link is out of date - the entry point is now http://visualstudio.com/get-started/package/what-is-packaging. Also, sorry about the 20 identities thing - we have a bug tracking that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The in-box NuGet Publish task has two options: "external" feeds and "internal" feeds. External feeds are intended for 3rd party services like NuGet.org, Artifactory, and expect a service connection with an API key.

Internal feeds are those hosted by Team Services. Instead of a service connection, you add the URL of the feed's NuGet endpoint. The build system relies on the Project Collection Build Service (for collection-scoped build definitions) or Project Build Service (for "this project"-scoped build defs) being a Reader or Contributor to the feed. Docs for all that are available [here](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/get-started/package/build/team-build).

Comment: Hi Matt, no worries - the bits that work are working well (the feed and the packaging step) the PowerShell scripts are greasing the wheels in the meantime :)

Comment: Hi Matt, any idea when this will be deployed?  Neither powershell nor Nuget Publisher is working at this point :(

Comment: It was deployed on November 24. Make sure you choose "internal" feed, and copy in the URL of your feed's NuGet endpoint. You can click the Connect to feed button in the web UI to get that.

Comment: I did, unfortunately it is not working.  Also feed generates `ApiKey` as **VSTS** where _NugetPublisher_ uses **VssSessionKey**.  I'm not sure if they are related or not.  You may find the detailed log in here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34079593/pushing-a-nuget-package-to-visual-studio-online-package-feed

Comment: I can select the 'internal' feed, but don't see a 'Connect to feed' on that screen..  
Is this publishing to the internal feed using the nuget publish task something that is going to be fixed soon?

Comment: @BartJanson the Connect to feed button is actually on the PACKAGE hub itself. See https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/get-started/package/use/publish. We're going to improve the publish task early next year to make this a lot more seamless (probably a dropdown feed picker rather than a copy-paste URL field).

Comment: @MattCooper Ah, thanks, yeah, I was confused by the connect button because my feed is still empty.
Hope that the publish-task is updated soon so that it can be used to publish to a vsts feed.

Comment: The publish task was updated in November to be able to publish to VSTS feeds. The work left is to make a feed drop down control instead of a raw text field for a URL, but everything else is in place.

Comment: AFAIK it still doesnt work , same error feed is right as i can publish  locally , its an authentication issue somehow its still prompting for user name and password for internal azure. Anyone got it working ?

Comment: Ok I explicitly had to set the Project Build Service not the collection to have publish rights

Answer (score 3):

UPDATE: It is all fixed now so you can use the standard packaging steps in vNext and they work like a charm.

For the time being, I am [substituting the NuGet Publisher step with a PowerShell build step](https://www.stevefenton.co.uk/2015/11/using-visual-studio-online-powershell-build-step-to-publish-nuget-package/).

This slots into the build after the "NuGet Packager" step and allows me to specify all of the credentials by setting up a package source before pusing the package.

```
$feedUrl = "https://example.pkgs.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/_packaging/Example/nuget/v3/index.json"

$packagePath =  $ENV:BUILD_REPOSITORY_LOCALPATH + "\YourOrg.YourComponent." + $ENV:BUILD_BUILDNUMBER + ".nupkg"

Write-Host "Adding package Source"
$addSourceCommand = $ENV:BUILD_REPOSITORY_LOCALPATH + "\nuget sources add -name ""Example"" -source " + $feedUrl + " -username ""your.username"" -password ""yourpassword"""
Invoke-Expression -Command $addSourceCommand

Write-Host "Pushing package to NuGet"
$pushCommand =  $ENV:BUILD_REPOSITORY_LOCALPATH + "\nuget push $packagePath -Source " + $feedUrl + " -ApiKey Example"
Invoke-Expression -Command $pushCommand
```

Answer (score 0):

I landed here because I'm researching/configuring an internal deploy -- where I'm running my own NuGet Server (nuget.server, as opposed to visual studio online). The error was the same (or has similar text):

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object

My solution, it turned out, was that the URL wasn't right. 
The correct version is: `http://server-name/NuGet/api/v2/package`

For completeness, I had: `http://server-name/NuGet/` which was wrong.