# Pushing a Nuget package to Visual Studio Online Package feed

Tags: nuget, azure-devops

I have the **Package** service enabled on my VSO account but when I try to push packages through build process, it throws an error.  Any advise?

## Error

> Please provide credentials for: https://ilerler.pkgs.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/_packaging/Main/nuget/v2/
>
> **##[error]Object reference not set to an instance of an object.**
>
> UserName: Password:
>
> ##[error]Unexpected exit code 1 returned from tool NuGet.exe

## Log

```
2015-12-04T01:36:28.1988899Z Set workingFolder to default: C:\LR\MMS\Services\Mms\TaskAgentProvisioner\Tools\agents\default\tasks\NuGetPublisher\0.1.39
2015-12-04T01:36:28.2008909Z Executing the powershell script: C:\LR\MMS\Services\Mms\TaskAgentProvisioner\Tools\agents\default\tasks\NuGetPublisher\0.1.39\NuGetPublisher.ps1
2015-12-04T01:36:28.3238908Z Check/Set nuget path
2015-12-04T01:36:28.3258901Z Creating Nuget Arguments
2015-12-04T01:36:28.3608909Z Getting credentials for Microsoft.TeamFoundation.DistributedTask.Agent.Common.TaskEndpoint
2015-12-04T01:36:28.8138749Z Setting credentials for httpsilerlerpkgsvisualstudiocomDefaultCollectionpackagingMainnugetv2
2015-12-04T01:36:28.9598774Z C:\a\1\NuGet
2015-12-04T01:36:28.9608764Z Saving to C:\a\1\NuGet\newNuGet.config
2015-12-04T01:36:28.9648769Z Pattern found in solution parameter.
2015-12-04T01:36:28.9658752Z Find-Files -SearchPattern C:\a\1\s\**\Ruya.Core.*.nupkg
2015-12-04T01:36:29.0488979Z Found files: 1
2015-12-04T01:36:29.0518782Z File: C:\a\1\s\Main\nuget\Ruya.Core.1.223.15337.20341.nupkg
2015-12-04T01:36:29.0528761Z Invoking nuget with push C:\a\1\s\Main\nuget\Ruya.Core.1.223.15337.20341.nupkg -s https://ilerler.pkgs.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/_packaging/Main/nuget/v2  -configFile "C:\a\1\NuGet\newNuGet.config" -apiKey VssSessionKey on C:\a\1\s\Main\nuget\Ruya.Core.1.223.15337.20341.nupkg
2015-12-04T01:36:29.0538797Z C:\LR\MMS\Services\Mms\TaskAgentProvisioner\Tools\agents\default\agent\worker\tools\NuGet.exe push C:\a\1\s\Main\nuget\Ruya.Core.1.223.15337.20341.nupkg -s https://ilerler.pkgs.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/_packaging/Main/nuget/v2  -configFile "C:\a\1\NuGet\newNuGet.config" -apiKey VssSessionKey
2015-12-04T01:36:29.8121321Z Pushing Ruya.Core 1.223.15337.20341 to 'https://ilerler.pkgs.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/_packaging/Main/nuget/v2'...
2015-12-04T01:36:30.0481938Z Using credentials from config. UserName: VssSessionToken
2015-12-04T01:36:30.8740306Z Using credentials from config. UserName: VssSessionToken
2015-12-04T01:36:31.3286903Z Please provide credentials for: https://ilerler.pkgs.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/_packaging/Main/nuget/v2/
2015-12-04T01:36:31.3426871Z ##[error]Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
2015-12-04T01:36:31.3436873Z UserName: Password: 
2015-12-04T01:36:31.4303476Z ##[error]Unexpected exit code 1 returned from tool NuGet.exe
```

Answer (score 2):

There is a same issue asked before, you can refer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33776694/vso-nuget-publisher-build-step-fails) for details. The root cause and the workaround is included in it.